# Flutter: FCM Push notification page routing problem

Tags: flutter, routes, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using `fcm_config` for receive push notification and show. Here is my code:

```
class FcmHelper {
  // prevent making instance
  FcmHelper._();

  static init() async {
    await _initNotification();
    _configureFCM();
  }

  static Future<void> _initNotification() async {
    await FCMConfig.instance.init(
      //  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      // Note once channel created it can not be changed
      // defaultAndroidForegroundIcon: "@mipmap/custom_icon",
      defaultAndroidChannel: const AndroidNotificationChannel(
        'fcm_channel',
        'Fcm config',
        importance: Importance.high,
        showBadge: true,
        enableVibration: true,
      ),
      displayInForeground: (notification) {
        return true;
      },
    );
  }

  static void _configureFCM() {
    // Add listeners for different notification events
    FCMConfig.instance.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('onMessage: $message');
    });
  }
}
```

but, there is no option for onTap. I want to, when users click on this notification it will navigate to selected page from Admin panel. and also another problem. When It app in background, notification will not pop, just show in notification list. How can I solve these problems ?